# Enable SSLv2 SSLv3 Ubuntu 18

Tags: ssl, openssl

Following this guide, `https://websiteforstudents.com/manually-install-the-latest-openssl-toolkit-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-lts/`, I installed OpenSSL 1.1.1. How can I enable SSLv2 and SSLv3 in order to use sslscan?

Comment: keep in mind both SSLv2 and SSLv3 are obsolete and should not be used in anger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "enable" SSLv2 and SSLv3 since support for these protocols is not compiled into the binary by default. You have to specifically compile OpenSSL with options to enable support, see [Simple way of enabling SSLv2 and SSLv3 in OpenSSL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893155/simple-way-of-enabling-sslv2-and-sslv3-in-openssl).